# Is it possible to have another QA event?

Tags: support, community-event

I am not sure if this should be posted here (or in chat), but I do miss the days of when QA had major events for big game releases.   In my opinion, these events created enormous amounts of traffic and activity on QA.

How does an event start and can we have another one soon?

Comment: I would love another event, but I don't think it's going to happen.  If it does, I'd prefer one that's not Destiny. :P

Comment: It doesn't have to be Destiny :P  *edited* I just miss the days of having events on here!

Comment: Those events weren't exactly cheap, both in prizes and SE manpower. I wasn't surprised when SE stopped doing them. But I'd guess that they'll be back occasionally on a smaller scale, I think you could make a case for doing that e.g. for a Skyrim successor.

Comment: What is QA? 123

Comment: @SimonW QA in arQAde, otherwords - gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ah. Thanks. That seems like an...odd choice of letters. Presumably there's a historical reason.

Comment: @SimonW Question and Answer site, not all that odd of a letterchoice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Word from on high was that the events themselves didn't increase traffic enough to justify their expense.

So due to **high level of effort** and **low return**, you're unlikely to see anything like these events again anytime soon.

Comment: boooo....... :(  But thank you for finding this out